# Fetching Sherpa info in OpenRefine

Tags: json, openrefine, grel

I have an OpenRefine project, an xml file, with a column including journal titles. I am trying to create a new column, fetching information from Sherpa/Romeo about the journal column. I tried "add column by fetching urls" and put:

'http://www.v2.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/api29.php?ak=MY-API-KEY&qtype=starts&jtitle=' + escape(value,'url')

But I just get an empty column.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I see that there are different APIs in Sherpa for this. I tried for example, Object Retrieval API, fetching data by publisher name instead of journal title, but still getting a blank column:
https://v2.sherpa.ac.uk/cgi/retrieve/cgi/retrieve?item-type=publisher&api-key=MY-API-KEY&format=Json&limit=5&offset=10

Comment: When you call the API, from `Add a column by fetching URLs` select `store error`. that can help to understand what is happening.

Comment: I just did it. How can I see the errors? Are they stored in a log files somewhere/

Comment: OpenRefine will display the error in the new column in red.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no red column! All that I get is a blanc column fetched from Sherpa.